# Pass schema value in place of array for creating document using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to pass schema details in the the place of array in my code. How can I do this in my controller ?

```
module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{ 
    var admin = new Admin();
    admin.email = req.body.email;
    admin.password = req.body.password;
    admin.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    admin.lastName = req.body.lastName;

    const reqq = crypto.createHash('md5').update(admin.companyName).digest('hex');

    let valueNum = reqq.match(/\d/g).join("").toString().substring(0,6);

    admin.companyID = valueNum;
     console.log(valueNum);

 const arrayObj = [{con:'IND'},{con:'USA'},{con:'JPN'}];

    admin.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err){

            res.send(doc);

            var thingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false, collection: valueNum });
            var Thing = mongoose.model(valueNum , thingSchema);
            var thing = new Thing(arrayObj); 
            thing.save();
            console.log(thing);
```

in the place of `arrayObj`, I need to pass my Schema model details so that I can use it to create document inside the collection which I am creating in the code.

**EDIT:-
Schema module file.**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName : {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    lastName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Last name can't be empty."
                },              
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty.",
                unique: true
                },
    password :  {
                type: String,
                required: "Password can't be empty",
                minlength: [6 ,"Password must be atleast 6 character long."]
                }
    saltSecret: String //this is user for encryption and decryption of password
});

mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

MongoDB nested object:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCCNS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to pass the `admin` document to `new Thing()`, you would first try to get its `doc.schema.obj` or `doc.schema.paths` (if you need the same `_id`), then you get all the propreties in an array, make an object with key value pairs and pass it to your `new Thing(arrObj)`.

```
admin.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(err) return err;
        res.send(doc);
        let arr = Object.keys(doc.schema.obj);
        let arrObj = {};
        arr.map(key => arrObj[key] = doc[key]);
        var thingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false, collection: valueNum });
        var Thing = mongoose.model(valueNum , thingSchema);
        var thing = new Thing(arrObj); 
        thing.save();
        console.log(thing);
})
```

I noticed your sending the document (`res.send(doc)`) before instanciating your `Thing` model, sure, `res.send()` only ends the HTTP response, and does not stop you code from running, but that's the only response you'd be able to send. You can only send one response.

Comment: No, you didn't get the question. As you can see I am exporting `Admin` module to the controller file. I want the same schema module to be in the place of `arrayObj`

Comment: "I want the same schema module to be in the place of `arrayObj`", what Schema are your refering to ? What do you mean by "in the place `of arrayObj`" ?

Comment: I am exporting schema from model file in controller. I want to have the model details  in `arrObj` . The array which I am passing right now is just for testing purpose. Instead of the array I want the schema details or as i say the `doc` details. See my EDIT ..including model file.

Comment: "schema details or as i say the doc details." do you want the schema propreties (field types ...) or the document (an instance of your class with 'fields' and values) ?

Comment: I want the document in `arrObj`

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and yes I want to send only one response. But in the database document nested object is being created. Copy of doc with new id. I am attaching screenshot of it.

Comment: According to your suggestion `new Thing(doc)`;, I am getting error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DocumentNotFoundError: No document found for query "{ _id: 5cab1eb1ad88d239e37a7 }"`

Comment: You're right, check new answer, use `doc.schema.paths` instead of `doc.schema.obj` if you need the same `_id` as your admin doc (I personally would not, ids are suppoed to be unique identifiers)

Comment: Thanks for your edit. This is what exactly I am looking for.